# How to create a query, which produce this explain plan? (oracle sql)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

The database is the example Oracle HR database: http://elsasoft.com/samples/oracle/Oracle.XE.HR/default.htm

The explain plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                     | Name              |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                   |
|  1 |  HASH UNIQUE                  |                   |
|* 2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | EMPLOYEES         |
|* 3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |
----------------------------------------------------------

Predictate Information (identified by operation id):
----------------------------------------------------

 2 - filter("MANAGER_ID" < 150)
 3 - access("DEPARTMENT_ID" < 50)
```

I tried this query, but it produced a very different result:

```
select /*+ use_hash(emp) */* 
  from HR.employees emp 
 where MANAGER_ID <150 and 
       DEPARTMENT_ID <50;
```

I've built the where statement from `filter`, and `access`. And the `use_hash` from `HASH_UNIQUE`. But the result is still very different, and I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: the `HASH UNIQUE` indicates that there is a `distinct` or possibly `group by` involved

Comment: I tried SELECT distinct `employee_id` from ... But still not UNIQUE_ID

Comment: Try like @JonHeller answer to do distinct on `first_name` or another non-indexed column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a precise explain plan is difficult and depends on the query, version, parameters, and undocumented hints.

In this case the main hint is probably the undocumented `USE_HASH_AGGREGATION`, but it must also be used in combination with a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.  But it also depends on which column is used - if the query did a distinct on only a primary key then it would not aggregate because the optimizer knows there's no need.

Since I'm using 12c I had to disable `_optimizer_batch_table_access_by_rowid`, but this isn't necessary for earlier versions.

The undocumented `format => '+outline'` feature is helpful to create exact plans.  If you're not using 12c it's hard to guarantee that it will work the same way.  [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2067c/3) works in 11gR2, but it's difficult to know if the hints are working or if it's just luck that the plan is the same.

**Query**

```
explain plan for
select
    /*+
        BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
        USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$1")
        INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$1" "EMP"@"SEL$1" ("EMPLOYEES"."DEPARTMENT_ID"))
        OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
        ALL_ROWS
        OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_batch_table_access_by_rowid' 'false')
        DB_VERSION('12.1.0.1')
        OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.1')
        IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
        END_OUTLINE_DATA
    */
    distinct first_name
from HR.employees emp 
where MANAGER_ID <150 and 
    DEPARTMENT_ID <50;
```

**Plan**

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +predicate +outline'));

Plan hash value: 2074795195

----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name              |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                   |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                 |                   |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMPLOYEES         |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |
----------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$1")
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$1" "EMP"@"SEL$1" ("EMPLOYEES"."DEPARTMENT_ID"))
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      ALL_ROWS
      OPT_PARAM('_optimizer_batch_table_access_by_rowid' 'false')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.1')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.1')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("MANAGER_ID"<150)
   3 - access("DEPARTMENT_ID"<50)
```

Comment: I got the desired plan on my 12.1.0.2.0 simply by `select distinct last_name
from employees emp 
where manager_id < 150
and department_id < 50` with no hints at all. I'd expect distinct first_name to do the same, or practically any distinct of any non-indexed column.

Answer (score 2):

First try to gather stats on the table, if the plan above makes sense then you'll get it

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('HR','EMP', cascade=>true);
```

If you still dont get this plan then oracle thinks there is a better plan (and he's usually right). 
To force this plan try

```
select /*+ USE_INDEX(eMP,EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX ) */ 
from HR.employees emp 
where MANAGER_ID <150 and DEPARTMENT_ID <50
```

Comment: thank you. Table access by index rowid, and index range scan is in the plan now. Only `HASH UNIQUE` is missing